# Check if another process is DPI aware on Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

How can I check if another process is dpi aware on Windows 7? I know there is `IsProcessDPIAware()`, but that only works for the calling process (and I'd rather not go the route of dll injection).
Another option would be to check if the `HIGHDPIAWARE` flag is set in the registry, but I don't know if this is reliable and I assume it is not very fast!?

Are there any other, better options?

Comment: There's literally a link to your answer in the [documentation of IsProcessDPIAware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isprocessdpiaware). Which is [GetProcessDpiAwareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getprocessdpiawareness)

Comment: I saw that link, but as I said I am looking for a solution on Windows 7 and `GetProcessDpiAwareness()` is available from Windows 8.1.

Comment: Querying any registry value or any other static data is certainly not reliable as DPI awareness can be changed dynamically through [`SetProcessDPIAware()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiaware). **Why** do you need to know whether a process is DPI aware?

Comment: Because I am taking screenshots of the windows of the target process and they are sized differently depending on the dpi awareness of the process.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-process_dpi_awareness#remarks):

> Previous versions of Windows(which means < 8.1) required you to set
>   the DPI awareness for the entire application. Now the DPI awareness is
>   tied to individual threads, processes, or windows. This means that the
>   DPI awareness can change while the app is running and that multiple
>   windows can have their own independent DPI awareness values.

In previous versions of Windows, DPI values were only set once for an entire application.
So check the registry setting of `HIGHDPIAWARE` flag in Window 7 is reliable and that's the way to check the another process's DPI Awareness.

Comment: But as zett42 mentioned, one can also set the DPI awareness programmatically using `SetProcessDPIAware()`. This would not be reflected in the registry.

Comment: @JohannesStricker `SetProcessDPIAware` sets the process-default DPI awareness to system-DPI awareness. And setting the process-default DPI awareness via API call can lead to unexpected application behavior.

Comment: Thank you, but I still think that checking the registry is a hacky solution. The user could, for example, change the registry value after he started the application, in which case the registry check would return a false result. Is there really no other way to do this?

Comment: I am afraid not as far as I know. Before windows 8.1, There is no per-monitor or per-thread,per-window, per-process dpi awareness level but only `PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE`.